I am getting Error: Minified React error #188; in Mui button base component
Detail error look like:
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #188; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=188 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at t.findDOMNode (react-dom.production.min.js:289:284)
    at t.value (ButtonBase.js:249:39)
    at xl (react-dom.production.min.js:260:217)
    at bl (react-dom.production.min.js:259:446)
    at yl (react-dom.production.min.js:258:431)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:282:96
    at wc (react-dom.production.min.js:280:398)
    at oc (react-dom.production.min.js:269:269)
    at A (scheduler.production.min.js:13:203)
    at MessagePort.R (scheduler.production.min.js:14:128)

My mui versions are: ^5.14.0
React version is: ^18.3.1,
I am getting this error only in production, I am not getting this error in development mode. Because of this error it is crashing whole page.

Did you follow the link in the error message (https://react.dev/errors/188?invariant=188) and see that the error is "Unable to find node on an unmounted component."? Looks like whatever .findDOMNode is searching for has been unmounted and therefore not useable. If you need more help than this you'll need to [edit] your code to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with, likely starting with that ButtonBase component file, if that's your code.
